# JPF configuration error: class not found gov.nasa.jpf.symbc.SymbolicInstructionFactory

Tags: java

I am trying to run Symbolic Java Path finder, howerver getting following error: 
SEVERE JPF configuration error: class not found gov.nasa.jpf.symbc.SymbolicInstructionFactory by classloader: gov.nasa.jpf.JPFClassLoader@aa470b8

> used within "vm.class" instantiation of class gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.JVM
>   SEVERE JPF terminated